# Animating transition on CSS inserted with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I'm struggling with getting a CSS transition to animate. I am inserting the new CSS I wish it to animate between with jQuery.

The text has the following transition statement on it when the page is first loaded:

```
#typer-expertise span{transition:color 1s ease-in;}
```

The following is then triggered and inserted with jQuery:

```
Line 46:    $('#'+outputIDName+' span').css('color','#e61873');
```

Thus changing the colour of the text to `#e61873`

However I had expected that this change of the attribute `color` would animate using the `transition` set on the element in CSS. But it doesn't, instead it merely "flashes" in (no colour fade/change)

What am I doing wrong? Is is the fault of adding the CSS with jQuery?

## https://jsfiddle.net/73cgurkL/1/

Answer (score 1):

You are much better of using add class to trigger transitions. like below.

Also set a timeout to stop jquery from just registering your color to the dom instantly.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $('#typer-expertise span').addClass('change');
}, 100);
```

```css
#typer-expertise span {
  color: #000;
  transition: color 1s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: color 1s ease-in;
}
#typer-expertise span.change {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="typer-expertise"><span>Change me</span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in a setTimeout as per [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/73cgurkL/2/).

```
setTimeout(function(){

  $('#' + outputIDName + ' span').css('color', '#e61873');

}, 0);
```

This forces a reflow of the DOM, which is sometimes needed when applying css properties directly after adding elements in order to honour an animation.

Comment: Hi there, this works great however I notice that it seems to cache somehow, as when I view it the first time it works OK but the second time it does not fade in the colour. Any ideas why that would happen or how I can fix it? For example, on my live version it fades in when incognito but in my normal browser window it does not fade http://digitalshowcase.somethingbigdev.co.uk

Comment: @Francesca perhaps a different script or style may be interfering with it. Are you using some sort of animation framework? Try setting the timeout to `1000` instead of zero and see what happens.

Comment: no animation frameworks in place. However changing the timeout to 100 makes it work and is a small enough amount of time that it cannot be detected as having a significant delay, so that works for me :)